# How can I bring back the console log on Android Studios using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, view, console

By default I always get the console in Android Studios that pulls up all of my print() messages. However when I minimize it, I can't seem to bring it back up under the View -> Tools section. Can someone tell me how to bring back the console log? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understand your problem, but please try press Alt+4.

If doesn't work please let me know.

Comment: Hey William it doesn't work for me - I am on a Mac so that may be why. My issue is I can't seem to bring up the tool window that displays print output from print(); statements in Flutter. That window was there upon startup but after minimizing it it's not there.

Comment: You can take a look at the android studio documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts